# Scrape/Get IMG Src from separate [EXTERNAL] page (with Javascript?)

Tags: php, javascript, html, image, src

I am looking to make a script, where, given a Youtube user it will pull the banner off of their channel. The Youtube channel will be user-inputed.

Example input: thenewboston

Note that, the location of the channel would be http://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston

And that is how all youtube channels URL's are formatted. Also notice that the banner image is in a **div with id="user_banner"**.

So the ideal output in this case (thenewboston's channel) would be http://i3.ytimg.com/u/JbPGzawDH1njbqV-D5HqKw/profile_header.jpg?v=4bba630b

Comment: and are you going to ask them permission first?

Comment: No? Youtube is completely public. If you can share their videos I think you can share their banners.

Besides, I am doing this for a "Profile" type look on a seperate page (they will be typing in their own channel)

Comment: on a web site does not mean you the right to use a you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Javascript, its difficult as you cannot make cross-site ajax requests. You will probably need to involve php in this. You can do in jQuery,

```
$.get(getYTBanner.php, variables)
```

and in getYTBanner.php, you will need to open this url using file_get_contents or cURL and from there get the banner through html.

Warning: not actual syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! PHP would actually be much easier to use if possible....sny other answers?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to get the image with html?